# WinSCP/PuTTY: Cannot move file on server via sudo: Permission denied

Tags: shell, putty, sudo, scp, winscp

I have uploaded a file to a remote Linux server.

current directory is: `/home/user/file.war`

Now i want to move the file into tomcat `webapps` folder and overwrite the existing version:

The directory I want to move it to is: `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps`

I tried it a few days ago using PuTTY, change to root user like this:

```
sudo -s
```

It asks for my user password and then as root i tried to copy the file with one of the following commands:

```
scp file.war root@ip:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps

sudo scp file.war root@ip:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps

scp /home/user/file.war root@server:/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps
```

Then it asks for my password again, but I only get a "Permission denied". The password seems to be alright, because otherwise I could not have logged in in the beginning. What am I doing wrong here?

Is it possible to get root access only with WinSCP? Logging in with sudo shell didn't work for me either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to copy a local file to another local directory.

So you want the plain `cp`, not the `scp`.

```
cp /home/user/file.war /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps
```

---

Regarding WinSCP: See FAQ [How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su)